# Date Value Code Not Running Properly

Tags: vba, datetime, excel

I am running a date value function that is not returning the correct dates. The code is returning all the same dates when it should be returning dates that go backward by single day increments.
For example, Friday 5/30, Thursday 5/29, Wednesday 5/28, Tuesday 5/27,....

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(R[-1]C)"
Range("B90").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B90:U90"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

When I go into Visual Basic to edit any part of the code and save the module, I go back to the Excel worksheet I am running the code on, and it looks like the worksheet updated and executed the code properly -- all the dates are correct. This only happens when I save Visual Basic. When I attempt to re-run the code with the saved module, it again does not initially work.

I have tried to re-start Excel and my computer several times to no avail.

This is likely an issue with Excel because the code should be executing properly, but not exactly sure how to proceed.

Any advice and help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Range("A90").Value = DateSerial(2014, 6, 2)
    Range("B90").Value = Range("A90") - 1
    Range("B90").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B90:U90"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```